# unregister anonymous BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am doing SMS sending functionality. I am registering using anonymous broadcast receiver. Now I get Exception to do unregister.

**Below is my code:**

```
public class SMSUtility
{
public static void sendSMS(final Context context, String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    MobiculeLogger.showInfoLog("SMS UTILITY", "Inside sendSMS");
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);




    // ---when the SMS has been sent---
    context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
    context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));



    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    MobiculeLogger.showInfoLog("SMSUTILITY ", "SMS = "+sms.toString());
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    MobiculeLogger.showInfoLog("SMSUTILITY ", "SEND TEXT MESSAGE phone number= "+phoneNumber+" message ="+message);


}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use like

```
BroadCastReceiver r = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
    {
        switch (getResultCode())
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

register using

```
context.registerReceiver(r, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
```

unregister using

```
context.unregisterReceiver(r);
```

Comment: Where to unregister (ie) after

Comment: if you register in oncreate unregister in ondestroy. if you register in onresume unregister in onpause.

Comment: But i have written it in non-activity class